# if statement containing a semi-colon

Tags: c#, syntax, if-statement

I've seen this if statement recently:

```
if(hWnd &gt; 0)
{
 ....
}
```

Can someone explain this syntax for me?

I've never seen a semi-colon in an if statement before.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's HTML encoded and that code won't compile correctly until it is decoded. It should be this:

```
if(hWnd > 0)
{
    ....
}
```

The `&gt;` is the [HTML (or XML) entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for `>`. You might also find that the code contains other entities such as `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 19):

It looks like an HTML-Encoded version of an if statement.

The `&gt;` would be converted to a greater-than symbol: `>`